# Fluid Dynamics: Stack manometer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

Is the pressure of the manometer at point E the largest in the system? I worked out the calculations and found that it was. Why is the pressure at point E not the same as the pressure at the dotted line of the U-Tube manometer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A close inspection of the drawing indicates that at the dotted line on the manometer, the pressure is due to the pressurized air in the tank plus the pressure from the 5 m static head of the oil that is in the left leg of the manometer.  On the other hand, the pressure at the bottom of the tank is due to the pressurized air in the tank, plus the pressure from the 2 m static head of oil, plus the pressure from the 3 m static head of water.  Since water is denser than oil, the pressure at the bottom of the tank is higher than the pressure at the dotted line of the manometer.